# How do I make my inputs stay uniform on all browsers all devices - if possible?

Tags: css, input

I have some issue which only encounters my `iPad Pro 12.9`, but not on phones or desktops.

## on :  Safari + Chrome + Firefox

[image]

```
input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=time] {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

How do I make my inputs `padding` look nice on all browsers all devices?

Comment: Try adding line-height to be more specific for Safari.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't look like you have padding on first 2 inputs at all, the last one looks like it's actually rendering padding, which seems like an unwanted behavior. Could you elaborate on the issue?

Comment: @ArnoTenkink Tried, `min-height: 34px; line-height:1.42857143;` still no luck;

Comment: Since there is no (uniformly) text in the inputs, how can you assess the padding? I can't see any difference (apart from the screensize and the red cross)...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to make sure your inputs aren't being over-ridden from another declaration which often causes the problem you have here, particularly in relation to the `line-height` and `font-size` properties. Set your line-height value to `line-height: normal` on your input elements. Using the `input[]` selector has a low specificity in the CSS cascade, hence why it could be being over-ridden.

If the above values aren't being over-ridden from a different part of your stylesheet you can use `box-sizing:border-box`, `line-height: normal` on your input elements. You'll most likely need to increase the padding value slightly to get the aesthetic look you require.

Answer (score 0):

How about to use [`all: unset;`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/all/)
To be honest I found out about it just yesterday and not used it yet, but it seems to be [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=all).

Here is [a small demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-hypatia-5g7m2?file=/src/styles.sass). Though, I used sass.

Screenshot from iPad Pro:
[image]

Screenshot from Chrome (on Linux):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need padding top and bottom within an input, so you can remove it, just use `padding: 0 10px`
If some browser do not vertically centres the text, you can equal the line-height with the height and that should be fine.

also apply a `box-sizing: border-box;` rule will probably avoid differences between browsers on how do they render paddings.